# How to replace appsettings.json variables on team services?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops, release-management

Im trying to make a CD enviroment with as `ASP.NET Core (.Net Framework)` using `team services`.
The build definition gerates a **zipped artifact** with the website.

Then in my Release configuration i would like to change some values of my `appsettings.json` properties, but the artifact is zipped, so apparently the release management has no access to the `appsettings.json` the logs says that `Error: NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: appsettings.json`, what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: What's the path to your appsettings.json file in the zip file?

Comment: The similar issue has been solved (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4637), check whether it works fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually run this task both for build and release successfully now. To troubleshooting the issue:

1. If your release was run on private agent, you should check in the drop folder to check if the artifacts are zipped.
2. In related build definition check if `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` has zip file. If there has no zip file, you can add **Archive Files** task to to zip files in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.
3. If the `appsettings.json` is no in the root of zip folder, use `**/appsettings.json` for **JSON variable substitution** in Azure App Service Deploy task.

Comment: but i dont have a xml, its a .json file.

Comment: I tested with .json file, you can refer https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4637.

Comment: I can build/deploy it successfully, you can have a try with above aspects.